# problema con salto de pagina en domPDF

Tags: dompdf

Hola estoy generando un PDF con DOMPDF y tengo en mi `style` estas propiedades para el `header` y `footer`:

```
 header { position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 1cm; right: 1cm; height: 2cm; }

 footer { position: fixed; bottom: 20px; left: 1cm; right: 1cm; height: 2cm; }
```

Esto me permite que mi pdf tenga un encabezado y un pie de página en todas las páginas que se generen. Pero cuando el pdf realiza un salto de página porque el contenido no cabe en un sola página, me mezcla el contenido del `body` con el del `header`. Existe alguna manera de poder solucionar esto?

Answer (score -1):

Mi amigo disculpa mi respuesta anterior ya consegui la respuesta de lo que me funciono te lo comparto espero te sea de ayuda

```
      <?php include_once "../conf/Configuracion.php"; ob_start(); ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
  <title>cecofal.com Tu solucion cooperativa</title>
  <head>
    <style> 
    /** Establezca los márgenes de la página en 0, por lo que el pie de página y el encabezado puede ser de altura   y     anchura completas. **/ 
      @page {
        margin: 0cm 0cm;
      }
  
      /** Defina ahora los márgenes reales de cada página en el PDF **/
      body {
        margin-top: 3cm;
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 2cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
      }
  
      /** Definir las reglas del encabezado **/
      header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 2cm;
        left: 2cm;
        right: 2cm;
        height: 3cm;

      }
  
      /** Definir las reglas del pie de página **/
      footer {
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 2cm; 
        left: 2cm; 
        right: 2cm;
        height: 2cm;
      }
      main {
        position: relative;
        top: 170px;
        left: 0cm;
        right: 0cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
      } 
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!---------- Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera ---------------------->
      <header> 
        <div id="photo" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="../imagenes/72.png" alt=""  width="150" style="vertical-align:middle"  />
          <h4 style="float:right;">
           Comprobante N#:<?php 
           $peticion = $db->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."'"); 
           $columna = $peticion->fetch_assoc(); 
           $item = array('comprobante' => $columna['comprobante'], 'fechafac'=>$columna['fechafac'], 'concepto'=>$columna['concepto'], 'desccripcion'=>$columna['descripcion'] );
           echo $item['comprobante'].' DE FECHA: '.date('d-m-Y',strtotime($item['fechafac']));?> </h4>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div  style="text-align: center">
          <font size="1"><strong>CONCEPTO:</strong> <?php echo $item['concepto']?></font> 
        </div>
      </header> 
<!---------- pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag   --------------------    --> 
      <footer>
       <center> 
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
          <?php $sentencia = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."'  "); 
            $productos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); ?>
            <?php $saldo = 0; $sumhaber= 0; $sumdebe = 0; 
            foreach($productos as $producto){
              $_SESSION['departamento'] = $producto->departamento;
              $_SESSION['comprobante']= $producto->comprobante;
              $sumhaber = $producto->haber + $sumhaber;
              $sumdebe = $producto->debe + $sumdebe;
              $_SESSION['sumhaber']=$sumhaber;
              $_SESSION['sumadebe']= $sumdebe; }
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td width="50%"></td>
                <td width="30%" align="right"><font size="1"><strong>TOTAL COMPROBANTE</strong></font></td>
          <td width="10%" align="right"><font size="1"><?php echo   number_format($_SESSION['sumadebe'],2,",",".")?>      </font></td>
          <td width="10%" align="right"><font size="1"><?php echo  number_format($_SESSION['sumhaber'],2,",",".") ?>      </font></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table width="100%" style="@media print{ border: 1px solid #000;  border-radius: 10px;  }  " >
            <tbody>
              <tr> 
                <td align="center"style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">BANCO</font></td>
                <td align="center"style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">CUENTA</font></td>
                <td align="center"style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">TIPO TRANSACCION</font></td>
                <td align="center"style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">SERVICIO</font></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr align="center"> 
              <td  style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1"><?php  $peticion2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM   diario     WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."' AND definicion='111' and mayor='201'");
                $columna2 = $peticion2->fetch_assoc(); 
          $item2 = array('banco' => $columna2['banco'], 'n_cuenta_ban'=>$columna2['n_cuenta_ban'], 'tipo_trasn_p'=>  $columna2['tipo_trasn_p'] ); 
  
                echo $item2['banco']?></font></td>
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1"><?php echo $item2['n_cuenta_ban'] ?></font></td>
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1"><?php echo $item2['tipo_trasn_p'] ?></font></td>
          <td  style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1"><?php if($_SESSION['departamento']=='6'){echo'      Servicio de Gas';} ?></font></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">COMPROBANTE</font></td>
                <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">HECHO POR:</font></td>
                <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">CONTABILIDAD</font></td>
                <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1">FECHA</font></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr align ="center">
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;"><font size="1"><?php echo $_SESSION['comprobante']?></font></td>
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
                <td  style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </footer> 
    <!---------- cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de    --------------------    --> 
      <main>
        <table width="100%"> 
        <?php $sentencia_diario = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."    '"); 
          $producto_diarios = $sentencia_diario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); ?> 
          <thead> 
           <tr>
            <td><center><font size="1"><strong>Codigo</strong></font></center></td>
            <td><center><font size="1"><strong>Descripcion</strong></font></center></td>
            <td><center><font size="1"><strong>Debito</strong></font></center></td>
            <td><center><font size="1"><strong>Credito</strong></font></center></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach($producto_diarios as $producto_diario){ ?>
            <tr> 
              <td><font size="1"><?php echo $producto_diario->codigo.' - '. $producto_diario->cuenta ;?></font></td>
              <td><font size="1"><?php echo $producto_diario->descripcion ?></font></td>
            <td align="right"><font size="1"><?php echo number_format($producto_diario->debe,2,",",".") ?></font></td  >
        <td align="right"><font size="1"><?php echo number_format($producto_diario->haber,2,",",".") ?></font></td>       </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>  
        </table> 
      </center> 
    </main> 
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php 
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  //echo $html;
  
  require_once "../dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
  // reference the Dompdf namespace
  use Dompdf\Dompdf;
  
  // instantiate and use the dompdf class
  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  
  
  $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
  $options->set(array('isRemoteEnable'=> true));
  $dompdf->setOptions($options);
  
  $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
  
  $dompdf->setPaper('letter');
  
  $dompdf->render();
  
  $dompdf->stream("reporte.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
  
  
  
  
  ?>
```

como podras notar en style uso una variedad de margenes solo debes jugar con ellos

Comment: Si quiere agregar un comentario a la pregunta, por favor utilice la sección de comentarios. Esta sección es solo para respuestas.